# How can I automatically upload war file to jboss and restart it

Tags: maven, deployment, jboss, web-deployment

We have a Java web application (maven enabled) that installed for all of our customers on their servers.

When one of my team members changes something inside the project, we have to manually upload the new version to all servers one by one using SSH and then restart the JBoss (4.0.4 GA) to changes takes effect.

This is very dangerous because any human mistake can be happened on customers servers and this is not what we want.

Is there any tool that can do the following steps automatically for me:

1. Upload an exploded war file (or any other file or directory) from specific path to servers one by one using SSH
2. Restart the servers JBoss or run some commands on them

**UPDATE**

We can use bash scripts to automate this process. Another solution is [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: Red Hat's JBoss Operations Network (I think the upstream project is RHQ) has some capability for managing deployments as "bundles" and also for performing, scripting or scheduling actions. I haven't looked into that side of it yet, so don't know if it could do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access the JBoss instance via the CLI, then you could probably use a CLI script. The script would contain the commands to deploy the new file then restart the server. You then start the CLI and pass the script as a parameter to invoke it. I don't have an instance available at the moment to test this on, but perhaps something like this:

**d:\deploy_script.cli**

```
deploy d:\deployments\new_app.war
:reload
```

To start the CLI and invoke the script would then be something like:

```
jboss-cli.bat --connect --file=d:\deploy_script.cli
```

Comment: I will test this solution. Thanks.

Comment: This is good and we can do it. Also Jenkins is another solution to automate deployment process.